# I'm getting an [] isn't defined for Object error in dart when following a Flutter Firebase tutorial?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
    return Sport(
       name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
       sport: doc.data['sport'] ?? '',
       age: doc.data['age'] ?? 0
    );

  }).toList();
}
```

I'm getting this error underneath ['name'], ['sport'], and ['age'] and I don't know how to fix it because for the guy in the tutorial, it's not giving him this error? I asked this question recently and based on the answer I changed my code to be this:

```
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
    final data = doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Sport(
       name: data['name'] ?? '',
       sport: data['sport'] ?? '',
       age: data['age'] ?? 0
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

But this still doesn't fix my error? I think it is because my age variable is an int and not a string. Can someone please let me know how to fix this because the guy in the tutorial I'm following is not getting these errors?

This is my Sport class:

```
class Sport {
   final String name;
   final String sport;
   final int age;

   Sport({required this.name, required this.sport, required this.age});
}
```

Comment: You can try print data in `final data = doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>;` ? 
I want to verify your data.

Comment: Try in your method: `int.parse(data['age'])??0`

Answer (score 0):

doc.data[] is deprecated. Use doc.get() instead and do it like this

```dart
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
    return Sport(
       name: doc.get('name') ?? '',
       sport: doc.get('sport') ?? '',
       age: doc.get('age') ?? 0
    );

  }).toList();
}
```